# PHP - open page base on id

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to open one page base on id from web address.

My address is …/customer-single.php?id=5

And my code is:

```
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $CustomerID = $_GET['CustomerID'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer WHERE CustomerID = :CustomerID";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':CustomerID', $CustomerID);
    $statement->execute();

    $user = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
```

So I need to see only result from CustomerID=5.

Comment: `$CustomerID = $_GET['CustomerID'];` should be `$CustomerID = $_GET['id'];` as the url has `id=` not `CustomerID=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following line

```
$CustomerID = $_GET['CustomerID'];
```

into

```
$CustomerID = $_GET['id'];
```

Because you need to specify the name of the parameter you have used in the url.

Answer (score 2):

$CustomerID = $_GET['CustomerID'];

change this into this

$CustomerID = $_GET['id'];

in here what you have done is trying to access a php GET variable using a unidentified reference. in get request you send your parameter like this **?id=5**
but when you access it, you try to access it in a wrong way . So what should actually happen is in order to access that GET variable you should reference it correctly like I have shown above